# How to paste the data in a range where the starting row and column of the range is defined in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have two sheets in my excel file:

**Input Sheet:** `Sheet1`

[image]

**Target Sheet:** `Sheet2`

[image]

What I want to achieve is to paste the value start from the column that I defined in cell `C5` and also start from the row that I defined in cell `C6`. If the range defined by cell `C5` and `C6` already have data, then it will find the next empty row based on the column in cell `C5` and paste the data in that empty row.

For example in the screenshot above, the starting column & row defined in cell `C5` & `C6` is `B8`, so the copied value will be pasted starting from cell `B8` until `E8`. However, if the row already have data, then it will find the next empty row based on column B (which is `B9`) and paste it there.

I'm not sure how to modified my current script:

```
Public Sub CopyData()

    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet ' set data input sheet
    Set InputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim InputRange As Range ' define input range
    Set InputRange = InputSheet.Range("G6:J106")
    
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Const TargetStartCol As Long = 2        ' start pasting in this column in target sheet
    Const PrimaryKeyCol As Long = 1         ' this is the unique primary key in the input range (means first column of B6:G6 is primary key)
    
    Dim InsertRow As Long

    InsertRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, TargetStartCol + PrimaryKeyCol - 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  
    ' copy values to target row
    TargetSheet.Cells(InsertRow, TargetStartCol).Resize(ColumnSize:=InputRange.Columns.Count).Value = InputRange.Value

End Sub
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

### Testing Scenario 1

[image]

### Output of Testing Scenario 1

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why the first row of data is repeated 5 times?

Comment: Because I run the script for 5 times, then this is the output, the second row will be overwritten when I run the script again

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Can you tell what's wrong with it? Never mind, I know what to do.

Comment: yes, I tested as well, the output is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Data to Another Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const rgAddress As String = "G6:J106"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)

    WriteCopyData rg

    ' or just:
    'WriteCopyData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G6:J106")

End Sub

Sub WriteCopyData(ByVal SourceRange As Range)

    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dRowAddress As String = "C6"
    Const dColumnAddress As String = "C5"
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = SourceRange.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = SourceRange.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = SourceRange.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = dws.Range(dRowAddress).Value
    Dim dCol As String: dCol = dws.Range(dColumnAddress).Value

    Dim dfrrg As Range: Set dfrrg = dws.Cells(dRow, dCol).Resize(1, cCount)
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = dfrrg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dRow + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
        Set dfrrg = dfrrg.Offset(dlCell.Row - dRow + 1)
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfrrg.Resize(rCount)
    drg.Value = SourceRange.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I've fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next code:

```
Public Sub CopyData_()
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet: Set InputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim InputRange As Range: Set InputRange = InputSheet.Range("G6:J106")
    Dim arr: arr = InputRange.Value
    
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet: Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim TargetStartCol As String, PrimaryKeyRow As Long
    TargetStartCol = TargetSheet.Range("C5").Value       ' start pasting in this column in target sheet
    PrimaryKeyRow = TargetSheet.Range("C6").Value        ' this is the row after the result to be copied
    
    Dim InsertRow As Long

    InsertRow = TargetSheet.cells(TargetSheet.rows.Count, TargetStartCol).End(xlUp).row + 1
    If InsertRow < PrimaryKeyRow Then InsertRow = PrimaryKeyRow + 1 'in case of no entry after PrimaryKeyRow (neither the label you show: "Row")
    ' copy values to target row
    TargetSheet.cells(InsertRow, TargetStartCol).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Not tested, but if should work, I think. If something not clear or going wrong, please do not hesitate to mention the error, what it does/doesn't against you need or anything else, necessary to correct it.

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru, if the input range have more than 1 row, seems like it only able to copy and paste the first row of the input range. The current input range is `G6:J106`, so ideally all the data in that range will be copied and pasted to the target sheet. Nevertheless, the pasting destination work perfectly!

Comment: @weizer The code can be easily adapted to do that. I will do it in seconds. But you did not specify that the copied range may have multiple rows...

Comment: @weizer Adapted. Using `arr` array it is easy to adapt the code. Please, test the updated one and send some feedback.

Comment: @weizer Did you find some time to test the updated code? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: It is able to paste the entire range of data already! I tested one scenario, but seems like the 2nd row of data will be overwritten, I guess is because of the `PrimaryKeyRow? I edited my question with 2 new screenshot

Comment: @weizer Did if you have a blank cell on the copied range, of course, next time, the last row being calculated for B:B will place the range in the next empty cell. You did not place only screenshots, you modified the question I answered... Of course, a solution can be found, but without asking for that, nobody can imagine what you have in mind, if you do not tell us.